# How to add JPanels to JScrollPane?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, jscrollpane

I'm implementing a simple chat application, using Java. I want my chat application to have the "bubble" message style like modern message apps, so I've built 2 classes `LeftArrowBubble` and `RightArrowBubble` which extend JPanel to illustrate sender & receiver bubbles, like this:

[image]

This is the code for my `LeftArrowBubble` class (quite alike for `RightArrowBubble`):

```
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Polygon;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.geom.Area;
import java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
/**
 * @author harsh
 */
public class LeftArrowBubble extends JPanel {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = -5389178141802153305L;
   private int radius = 10;
   private int arrowSize = 12;
   private int strokeThickness = 3;
   private int padding = strokeThickness / 2;
   @Override
   protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
      final Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
      g2d.setColor(new Color(0.5f, 0.8f, 1f));
      int x = padding + strokeThickness + arrowSize;
      int width = getWidth() - arrowSize - (strokeThickness * 2);
      int bottomLineY = getHeight() - strokeThickness;
      g2d.fillRect(x, padding, width, bottomLineY);
      g2d.setRenderingHints(new RenderingHints(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON));
      g2d.setStroke(new BasicStroke(strokeThickness));
      RoundRectangle2D.Double rect = new RoundRectangle2D.Double(x, padding, width, bottomLineY, radius, radius);
      Polygon arrow = new Polygon();
      arrow.addPoint(20, 8);
      arrow.addPoint(0, 10);
      arrow.addPoint(20, 12);
      Area area = new Area(rect);
      area.add(new Area(arrow));
      g2d.draw(area);
   }
}
```

Now I have a JFrame window with a `JScrollPane` on it, which looks like this:

[image]

What I want to do now is when I click on that `CreateNewBubble` button, a new `Left(or Right)ArrowBubble` JPanel will be created & displayed inside that `JScrollPane` (and this `JScrollPane` will be vertical scrollable if there're more bubbles inside of it). I've already tried this way:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    BubbleTest.LeftArrowBubble leftArrowBubble = new BubbleTest.LeftArrowBubble();
    jScrollPane1.add(leftArrowBubble);
}
```

But it didn't work as I expected: nothing shows up in the `JScrollPane` after clicking the button!
I've been stuck at this problem for hours, really appreciate if you guys can help!

Comment: Please try try posting the Main application code to enable us to assist you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `.add` that way on a JScrollPane. A JScrollPane can only scroll a single component, which is set by either passing it to its constructor, or by calling `.setViewportView`.

Instead, create a separate container for the bubbles, such as a vertical Box, and set that as the single component scrolled by the scroll pane:

```
Box box = new Box(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
JScrollPane jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(box);
```

When you add a bubble, add it to the box (and call `.revalidate()` to lay it out):

```
box.add(leftArrowBubble);
box.revalidate();
```

---

Edit: Also, your bubbles will not, by default, have any size, unless you give them a size such as by calling `setPreferredSize` or by overriding `getPreferredSize` or by putting components inside them.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I've just edited my code like what you suggested, but nothing seems to change yet :( Can you take a look at my code please: http://tny.cz/24666822

Comment: @rainman_TS7 Your JScrollPane is created by the generated code, so use that rather than creating a second JScrollPane. So call `jScrollPane1.setViewportView(box);`. You need to do that *after* creating the box component, otherwise the box variable is still null. Also you're calling `setPreferredSize` on the wrong thing; call it on the bubble, not the JFrame.

Comment: Sorry, I've just updated my code just like what you've said, but again, it not seems to be working... I press the button and no thing shown up inside the jScroolPane1 :( This is my new code: http://tny.cz/b50bbf5d

Comment: @rainman_TS7 You need to remove this line: `jScrollPane1 = new JScrollPane(box);`. Your scroll pane is already being created in the `initComponents` method.

Answer (score 2):

With JScrollPane you should always add components to the scroll pane's JViewPort. Look at the documentation [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/), it explains the concept behind the class rather well.

Short summary: A JScrollPane holds the scroll bars and a view port. The view port is a component that displays only a portion of its content - in this case the part that is visible on screen. The scroll bars tell the view port which portion to show.